# Oauth Between Jira and Apache Rave (shinding)

Tags: oauth, jira, opensocial

I try desperately to establish the oauth between Jira and Apache Rave but without success,
I try with Key Private / Public.
I was created two keys Private/Public with openssl, and i put the public key and consumer key (here i use this "OpenSocial" like consumer key) in Jira.
Now i d'not know where i put my private key in apache shinding rave 
please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

If Jira is the OAuth provider (responsible for handing out the keys & secrets) and Apache Rave is the OAuth consumer, you can configure the consumer keys & secret in the bundled Shindig. At the moment Apache Rave does not have a user interface for this, so you need to insert it into your database.
See http://rave.apache.org/documentation/oauth-consumer.html how to do this.